# Send commands to a running java process

Tags: java, server

I am making an HTTP server for a networking class that I am attending,I have made the server and now I want to be able to run the server in a terminal (say the name of the executable is myserver) and by opening another terminal I want to be able to issue commands to the already running process of the server,so instead of typing `myserver` to start the server ,I want to be able to type for example `myserver --quit` and the quit command will be send to the already running instance of the server,just like `adb` for android works.

So the flow of events should be something like that:

**Terminal 1:**

```
user$:myserver
server is running and listening
```

**Terminal 2:**

```
user$:myserver
server is already running
user$:myserver --quit
server has stopped
```

Whats the general idea behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with Sockets. The first terminal is the Server and the second one is the client. Then you can send/receive messages and handle them in the server. Look at Oracle's example of client-server http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: It crossed my mind but I thought it will make the things way more complex since I am already using ServerSocket for the httpserver ,but thinking about it makes more and more sense,this way I will be able to even issue commands on a server running on another machine.